# Change UIPopoverView background + arrow color

Tags: ios, uiview, swift, ios8, uipopoverbackgroundview

Is there a way to *simply* change the UIPopoverView background color (including its arrow) on iOS8?

(I did read a couple of articles on customizing "UIPopoverControllers". Does this apply here too, meaning the answer is "no"?)

[image]

Isn't this something I should be able to address in the **prepareForSegue** method triggering the popover? How can I reach the according view to change its appearance?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I found the solution. Subclassing is not necessary anymore with iOS8! The background can be accessed and changed like this from within the tableview -> navigation -> popoverPresentationController

```
    self.navigationController?.popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

More information about this in WWDC session 2014.

Comment: I add this to viewDidLoad of the controller that invokes the popover and nothing happens. Where should this go?

Comment: @TravisM. the popoverPresentationController isn't available then. Try "viewWillAppear" instead.

Comment: @Matthew, I did try that and it does not work. However, I can set `sourceRect` and `sourceView` at the same place.

Comment: if your popover doesn't have a navigation controller then use `self.popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red`

Comment: this does not change arrow color

Comment: Is it working in iOS 15?

Answer (score 10):

You can simply modify popover like this:

```
    let popoverViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("popoverSegue")
    popoverViewController!.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
    popoverViewController!.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover


    let popoverSize = CGSize(width: 150, height: 60)
    popoverViewController!.preferredContentSize = popoverSize
    let popover = popoverViewController!.popoverPresentationController
    popover?.delegate = self
    popover?.permittedArrowDirections = .Up
    popover?.sourceView = self.view

    //change background color with arrow too!
    popover?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    popover?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width, y: -10, width: 0, height: 0)
    presentViewController(popoverViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 6):

Seems like that popoverPresentationController.backgroundColor no longer works in iOS13.

Popover arrows now appear to take on the color of the popover viewController's view.backgroundColor.

Here's the whole code for the demo below:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let sourceButton = sender as? UIButton, let popover = segue.destination.popoverPresentationController {
        popover.sourceView = sourceButton.superview
        popover.sourceRect = sourceButton.frame
        popover.permittedArrowDirections = [.left]
        popover.delegate = self
        segue.destination.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        //popover.backgroundColor = sourceButton.tintColor  //old way
        segue.destination.view.backgroundColor = sourceButton.tintColor  //new way
    }
}

@IBAction func btnTap(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "popoverSegue", sender: sender)
}

func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**SwiftUI : Xcode 11.5**

Add the `.background` modifier with the color and add `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea` modifier.

```
.popover(isPresented: self.$vm.presentMenu, content: {
        self.menuView
           .background(Color.bgGray.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Just adding that if you are using SwiftUI inside of a UIPopover or if you are using SwiftUI's popover modifier you can set the background color of the popover by just using a `Color` in the background, like as in a `ZStack`.

If you want the arrow colored you can add the `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` modifier to the color in the background so it will extend into the arrow.

SwiftUI example:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct PopoverTest: View {
    @State var showing: Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        Button("Show") {
            self.showing.toggle()
        }
        .popover(isPresented: $showing) {
            ZStack {
                Color.green.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) // will color background and arrow
                Text("Popover!")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PopoverTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PopoverTest()
    }
}
```