# Change Popover colors in SWIFT 4

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I searched for a way to do this but found no answers! I can change the background color of the buttons, but not the arrow color.

So far I've done this:

```
let alert: UIAlertController    = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
alert.view.tintColor            = themeTextColor
alert.view.backgroundColor      = themeDialog
```

I've also tried this:

```
alert.popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor = themeDialog
```

but it doesn't change anything.

The result looks like this:

[image]

See the white areas?

Answer (score 1):

Change the background color of your presentationController to your desired color.

```
    public static func newInstance(_ sourceView: UIView) -> PlayerOptionsPopupViewController {
        let controller = PlayerOptionsPopupViewController()
        controller.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        controller.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        if let presentationController = controller.popoverPresentationController {
                presentationController.delegate = controller
                presentationController.permittedArrowDirections = arrowDirection
                presentationController.sourceView = sourceView
                presentationController.sourceRect = sourceView.bounds
                presentationController.backgroundColor = UIColor.bsBalloon // Your Color Here

         }
        return controller
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25403258/change-uipopoverview-background-arrow-color

Answer (score 0):

you can change alert view controller colour after presenting it. You are going right in somewhere, but you need to write following code.

```
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
       alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.red
       alert.view.backgroundColor = .green
})
```

tintColor will change color of action button and background color will change background of alert view.

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Paul , but it didn't fix my problem... I edited the question so you can see how it looks like... The background changes, but it's like there is some other layer behind that I'm not changing!

Comment: Have you try in device ?

Comment: Nothing changed

Answer (score -1):

In the presenting view controller, try this…

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let popoverPresentationController = segue.destination.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverPresentationController.backgroundColor = themeDialog
    }
}
```